# Saving to a specific path with the save prompt

Tags: macos, path

How do you save to specific paths with the save prompt WITHOUT navigating through the GUI? It's extremely annoying how I cannot just write paths into the save-as dialog box.

Comment: You can navigate through the icons just as if you were writing a path, just press `⌘`+`o` instead of `/`

Comment: →  XAleXOwnZX: I entered `⌘`+`S` on this page and tried `⌘`+`O`. This doesn't do anything.
Could you explain your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to navigate to the folder you want to save in (there's even tab complete!), press enter, then type the filename.

Comment: Beautiful. Could be useful occasionally

Comment: omfg thank you. i don't know why this is so embedded..